# Running rJAGS when the likelihood is a custom density

Tags: r, jags, rjags

I am trying to figure out how to sample from a custom density in `rJAGS` but am running into issues. having searched the site, I saw that there is a zeroes (or ones) trick that can be employed based on `BUGS` code but am having a hard time with its implementation in `rJAGS`. I think I am doing it correctly but keep getting the following error:

```
Error in jags.model(model1.spec, data = list(x = x, N = N), n.chains = 4,  : 
  Error in node dpois(lambda)
Length mismatch in Node::setValue
```

Here is my `rJAGS` code for reproducibility:

```
library(rjags)

set.seed(4)
N = 100
x = rexp(N, 3)
L = quantile(x, prob = 1) # Censoring point
censor = ifelse(x <= L, 1, 0) # Censoring indicator

x[censor == 1] <- L



model1.string <-"
  model {
    for (i in 1:N){
    x[i] ~ dpois(lambda)
    lambda <- -N*log(1-exp(-(1/mu)))
    }
  mu ~ dlnorm(mup, taup)
  mup <- log(.0001)
  taup <- 1/49
  R <- 1 - exp(-(1/mu) * .0001)
}
"
model1.spec<-textConnection(model1.string)


jags <- jags.model(model1.spec,
                   data = list('x' = x,
                               'N' = N),
                   n.chains=4,
                   n.adapt=100)
```

Here, my negative log likelihood of the density I am interested in is `-N*log(1-exp(-(1/mu)))`. Is there an obvious mistake in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Using the zeros trick, the variable on the left-hand side of the `dpois()` relationship has to be an N-length vector of zeros.  The variable `x` should show up in the likelihood somewhere.  Here is an example using the normal distribution.

```
set.seed(519)
N <- 100
x <- rnorm(100, mean=3)
z <- rep(0, N)
C <- 10
pi <- pi



model1.string <-"
  model {
    for (i in 1:N){
    lambda[i] <- pow(2*pi*sig2, -0.5) * exp(-.5*pow(x[i]-mu, 2)/sig2)
    loglam[i] <- log(lambda[i]) + C
    z[i] ~ dpois(loglam[i])
    }
  mu ~ dnorm(0,.1)
  tau  ~ dgamma(1,.1)
  sig2 <- pow(tau, -1)
  sumLL <- sum(log(lambda[]))
}
"
model1.spec<-textConnection(model1.string)


set.seed(519)
jags <- jags.model(model1.spec,
                   data = list('x' = x,
                               'z' = z, 
                               'N' = N, 
                               'C' = C, 
                               'pi' = pi),
                   inits = function()list(tau = 1, mu = 3), 
                   n.chains=4,
                   n.adapt=100)



samps1 <- coda.samples(jags, c("mu", "sig2"), n.iter=1000)
summary(samps1)

Iterations = 101:1100
Thinning interval = 1 
Number of chains = 4 
Sample size per chain = 1000 

1. Empirical mean and standard deviation for each variable,
   plus standard error of the mean:

      Mean     SD Naive SE Time-series SE
mu   4.493 2.1566 0.034100         0.1821
sig2 1.490 0.5635 0.008909         0.1144

2. Quantiles for each variable:

       2.5%   25%   50%   75% 97.5%
mu   0.6709 3.541 5.218 5.993 7.197
sig2 0.7909 0.999 1.357 1.850 2.779
```